# C++ vector, return vs. parameter

Tags: c++, stl, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to “return an object” in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350385/how-to-return-an-object-in-c)

I am wondering if there is a difference between the three following approaches:

```
void FillVector_1(vector<int>& v) {
    v.push_back(1); // lots of push_backs!
}

vector<int> FillVector_2() {
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1); // lots of push_backs!
    return v;
}

vector<int> FillVector_3() {
    int tab[SZ] = { 1, 2, 3, /*...*/ };
    return vector<int>(tab, tab + SZ);
}
```

Comment: Just return by value and worry about performance when you feel it's actually a problem. Then profile it so you don't have to guess. I'm preemptively closing as [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350385/how-to-return-an-object-in-c).

Comment: I would not have voted to close this as a duplicate for a couple reasons: (1) The earlier question had specifics about dynamic memory allocation that don't apply to this question, and (2) this question is STL-specific which can invoke other idioms like insert iterators.  Also, some implementations of STL already take advantage of C++0x r-value references to minimize copying.  That method doesn't apply in the earlier question.

Comment: @GMan: While I agree with the sentiment to not prematurely micro-optimize, I don't agree with the sentiment that one should return large objects by-value as a matter of course.  Especially when the STL collections are concerned, there are better ways.  For instance, by writing the function to accept an output iterator we can make it more adaptable and more STL-ish, while avoiding having to rely on RVO or funky compiler optimizations that might change the behavior of your program in an undesirable way.  Besides, C++ programmers should know when their objects are being copied - not code & pray

Comment: @John: It's not code and pray, it's code and get-your-program-working-then-profile-it-to-see-what-can-be-sped-up-and-stop-freaking-guessing. @Adrian @John: The iterator design is indeed probably the best way to code this, but as it stands the question itself is clearly just an unwarranted case of "oh surely I cannot return by value!". But as I like to look beyond the face of the question and solve the "real" problem, you're right; I'm voting to re-open.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The biggest difference is that the first way appends to existing contents, whereas the other two fill an empty vector. :)

I think the keyword you are looking for is [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), which should be rather common (with G++ you'll have to turn it off specifically to prevent it from being applied). That is, if the usage is like:

```
vector<int> vec = fill_vector();
```

then there might quite easily be no copies made (and the function is just easier to use).

If you are working with an existing vector

```
vector<int> vec;
while (something)
{
    vec = fill_vector();
    //do things
}
```

then using an out parameter would avoid creation of vectors in a loop and copying data around.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the difference between initialization and assignment w.r.t. copy elision.

Answer (score 9):

The idiomatic C++ approach would be to abstract over the container type by using an output iterator:

```
template<typename OutputIterator>
void FillContainer(OutputIterator it) {
    *it++ = 1;
    ...
}
```

Then it can be used with vector as:

```
std::vector<int> v;
FillContainer(std::back_inserter(v));
```

The performance (and other advantages, such as being able to fill a non-empty container) are the same as for your option #1. Another good thing is that this can be used to output in a streaming mode, where results are immediately processed and discarded without being stored, if the appropriate kind of iterator is used (e.g. `ostream_iterator`).

Comment: +1.  This seems like the most "STL way."  Note that it might be useful to return the iterator from `FillContainer`.

Comment: How does this work when "FillContainer" is a method of a class?

Comment: @User: same way - class member functions can also be templated. What you can't do with such a thing is make it virtual.

Answer (score 6):

One would assume parameter is best, but in practice it often is not. This depends on compiler. Some compilers (I think actually most recent compilers) will apply [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) - Visual Studio 2005 and later should do it in both cases you have provided (see [Named Return Value Optimization in Visual C++ 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057%28VS.80%29.aspx)).

The best way to know for sure is to check the disassembly produced.

Comment: This is a _huge_ optimization, and most modern compilers leverage it with big gains in performance.

Comment: The whole idea of RVO makes me cringe.  I hate it.

Answer (score 5):

Adding a fourth variant into the mix:

```
void FillVector_4(vector<int>& v) {
   static const int tab[SZ] = {1,2,3, ... };
   v.assign(tab,tab+SZ);
}
```

If you're thinking about performance version 2 and version 3 *may* make the compiler create a `vector<int>` copy for the return value. That is, if the compiler isn't able to do NRVO (named return value optimization). Also, consecutive `push_back`s without a `reserve` probably leads to a couple of reallocations since the vector needs to grow. Whether this matters at all depends on your problem you're trying to solve.

You'll be pleased to know that C++0x will make returning a locally created vector very efficient. I also recommend reading David Abrahams [article series](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) about efficient value types including passing/returning.

Answer (score 2):

The first definitely does not copy the vector.

The cost of copying the vector could be linear in the number of elements in the vector.

The first introduces no risk of linear behavior on any platform or compiler, and no costs of profiling and refactoring.

Comment: The first also allows to call several functions in a row to fill a single vector. If you need to do the same with #2, you'll have to copy elements from the vector being returned (which means that all the heroic RVO efforts by the compiler will be for nothing, since you'll end up with an immediately-discarded copy anyway).

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, the first two probably have more resizing of the vector going on, whereas the 3rd one probably does not need to resize the vector as it runs.  This can be mitigated by resizing it yourself before the pushbacks.