# Returning a c++ std::vector without a copy?

Tags: c++, stl, copy, return-value, temporary

Is it possible to return a standard container from a function without making a copy?

Example code:

```
std::vector<A> MyFunc();

...

std::vector<A> b = MyFunc();
```

As far as I understand, this copies the return value into a new vector b. Does making the function return references or something like that allow avoiding the copy?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703302/c-vector-return-vs-parameter/3703325#3703325?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If your compiler supports the NRVO then no copy will be made, provided certain conditions are met in the function returning the object.  Thankfully, this was finally added in [Visual C++ 2005 (v8.0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057(VS.80).aspx)  This can have a major +ve impact on perf if the container is large, obviously.

If  your own compiler docs do not say whether or not it's supported, you should be able to compile the C++ code to assembler (in optimized/release mode) and check what's done using a simple sample function.

There's also an excellent broader discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134831/in-c-is-it-still-bad-practice-to-return-a-vector-from-a-function)

Comment: Thanks! Any idea about NRVO in gcc?

Comment: @static_rtti - I will have to defer to Linux folks for that one, for fear of putting foot in mouth

Comment: You can easily test with a class that traces in the Copy CTor. Note that this is a "can be" optimization, that won't necessarily work e.g. with differentrly named return objects. However, with C++0x rvalue references, classes can implement a guarantee. You can expect this for standard containers in an up-to-date STL.

Comment: AFAIK, with GCC you'll have to turn this optimization off with -fno-elide-constructors, as it is otherwise enabled even with -O0.

Comment: @static_rtti: GCC is very good at eliding unnecessary copies. As far as I know, *no* other compiler is *better* at this -- just equally good or worse.

Comment: Agree with peterchen, there are a number of situations NRVO won't kick in, outlined in your linked document.  I think the answer should discuss C++0x move semantics to deserve being the top-voted and chosen answer, so unfortunately I'm downvoting this.  The compiler is never required to perform any optimization - with move semantics you can require the compiler not make a copy.

Answer (score 19):

Rvalues ("temporaries") bound to `const` references will have their lifetime extended to the end of the reference's lifetime. So if you don't need to modify that vector, the following will do:

```
const std::vector<A>& b = MyFunc();
```

*if* you need to modify the vector, just code it the way that's easiest to read until your have proof (obtained through profiling) that this line even matters performance-wise.

Otherwise rely on C++1x with its rvalue references and move semantics coming along "real soon now" and optimizing that copy out without you having to do anything.

Answer (score 3):

If you can modify the signature of the function then you can use

```
std::vector<A>& MyFunc();
```

or

```
void MyFunc(std::vector<A>& vect);
```

You could also return a smart pointer, but that involves newing the object.

```
some_smart_pointer<std::vector<A>> MyFunc();
```

HTH

Comment: The first one is likely not going to work if you are returning a vector that's a local in the function. The second one is fine though

Comment: +1 For the second form being the usual way to do this.  The problem with the first example `std::vector<A>& MyFunc();` is that the vector has to be allocated somewhere - `MyFunc` can't allocate it on the stack and return a reference.  It is possible if the vector is a class member and you are just returning a reference to an existing vector.

Comment: @John Burton/@beezler - 'not going to work' is putting it mildly, assuming the returned container is stack-based in the called function.

Comment: @John Burton/@Steve Townsend: why exactly isn't it going to work?

Comment: @static_rtti: If the object is allocated on the stack, it will go out of scope when the function returns.  So you're left holding a reference to an object that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Because it will be "destructed" when the function ends so you'll be returning an reference to a variable that doesn't exist any more. Your compiler will likely warn you though at least