# return vector<Foo> or shared_ptr<vector<Foo>>?

Tags: c++, boost, vector, c++11, shared-ptr

in a function, which "return" would be more appropriate?

A. `vector<Foo>` ?

B. `shared_ptr<vector<Foor>>` ?

In other words, which copy is less heavy, what would you do, and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate/related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721217/returning-a-c-stdvector-without-a-copy

Comment: Check your compiler, but you can normally assume elision WILL happen, in which case return-by-value is the fastest way. It's also the best way for semantics (idempotence, const result assignment, etc), see [this article](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)

Comment: And why isn't `unique_ptr` an option? Returning a `shared_ptr` implies that the function is keeping a copy; returning a `unique_ptr` lets everyone know that ownership is being fully transferred.

Comment: @NicolBolas unique_ptr is also an option, and so is intrusive_ptr etc.. same question. the question is a smart pointer should be used at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think returning `shared_ptr<vector<T>>` rarely is useful. I would only do this if several objects where to hold a shared vector that they could manipulate. To me this indicates a design flaw. A better alternative is probably to return by const reference. This avoids (a potentially expensive) copy operation, but does not allow the accessor to alter the vector.

If you are returning a local `std::vector` you could also return it by argument.

If you really want to return `shared_ptr<vector<T>>`, consider if `shared_ptr<const vector<T>>` would do the job (the vector can be inspected by many, but only manipulated by the owner).

However A is generally more expensive than B, but return value optimizations often applies here. For C++11 `std::vector` has a move constructor that will guarantee that returning a local `std::vector` won't require expensive copy operations.

Remember, don't prematurely optimize :)

Comment: All of this is ignoring RVO/NRVO which makes the question moot in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Returning `shared_ptr<vector<Foo>>` guarantees no extra copy will occur.

Returning `vector<Foo>` *may* avoid extra copy if return value optimization (RVO) kicks in, or if move semantics from C++11 is used. But if it's important to avoid copy I wouldn't use this (even if you can ensure these optimizations will always be available), because I don't think it's a good idea to use return-a-copy semantics while actually meaning not copying.

I would probably go with one of these, but it depends:

- pass a reference to `vector<Foo>` as parameter
- pass insert iterator (e.g. `back_inserter`) instead

Comment: about the reference: Right, because it will be destroyed in the end of the function scope. I'm cross compiling over different platforms, ios using xCode, vs2010. whcih do you recommand then?

Comment: @AlonAmir See the updated answer. If avoiding copy is important, don't pass `vector` by value.

Comment: *pass a reference to the `vector<Foo>` as parameter*: I wouldn't, if the function *creates* the vector internally, then it is a return value. The calling convention for all compilers I know of, in the case of a return type that does not fit in registers will implement that for you: the caller allocates the space and passes a pointer to the calle, the callee then initializes that memory with a real object (calling the appropriate constructor depending on the code). The effect is that you get a cleaner interface with exactly the same cost.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Right, that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid, making functions that receive "out" parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In C++03, prefer:

1. If providing access to a member, return by const reference.
2. Else if returning a local, use an out reference parameter.

In C++11, prefer:

1. If providing access to a member, return by const reference.
2. Else if returning a local, return by by value, as move construction will
   avoid excessive copies.

The situation where you would want to return a reference counted smart pointer would be where multiple objects with disjoint lifetimes will all want to access the object.  This is not the most common scenario however, but it does happen often enough.

Comment: I disagree with both #2 suggestions. Copy elision/RVO/whatever-they-want-to-call-it can make a lot of returning of containers cheap. And unless you're returning a temporary, move constructors will only be invoked if you explicitly ask for them via `std::move`. Either way, it's better to use copy elision.

Comment: C++03: you never return a reference to a local variable.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs - You should parse my language more carefully.  If the thing you would be returning would be local to the function, then pass in an instance of the object by reference as a *parameter* instead.