# If A std::vector is Returned-By-Value when Is It Freed?

Tags: c++, opencv, stl

I am having trouble understanding how the C++ std::vector container would get freed in the following scenario

```
void DoSomething()
{
   cv::Point ** curves;
   int * curve_sizes;
   num_curves = m_curves.size(); //member variable holdings curves
   curves = new cv::Point*[num_curves];
   curve_size = new int[num_curves];

   std::vector<cv::Point> cur_points;
   for(int i = 0; i < num_curves; ++i)
   {
     cur_points = CreatePolyPoints(m_curves[i]);
     curves[i] = &cur_points[0];
     curve_sizes = cur_points.size();
   }

   cv::fillPoly(m_roi, curves, curve_sizes, num_curves, ... );

   //Clear the dynamic data
   // Do i do aything here?   
   delete [] curves;
   delete [] curve_sizes;
}

std::vector<cv::Point> CreatePolyPoints(Curve curve)
{
   std::vector<cv::Point> points;

   //Do work here here
   while(something)
   {
     cv::Point cur_point;
     points.push_back(cur_point);
   }

   return points;
}
```

Thanks in advance.  If anyone is interested in my goal: Generate an ROI given polygons defined by "n" curves.

Comment: What is `curve_polygons`? Did you `new[]` it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not dynamically allocated so it will be destroyed as soon as it goes out of scope. In your case, your variable will go out of scope after the `DoSomething()` function exits. Your local variable `cur_points` gets the return value of `CreatePolyPoints()` assigned to it within your loop. When this happens, the old contents of `cur_points` will no longer exist - you do not need to worry about this, as the instances of `Curve` objects within that vector will get destroyed each time the vector gets reassigned. Similarly when `cur_points` goes out of scope.

EDIT: You do seem to have a problem here

```
std::vector<cv::Point> cur_points;
for(int i = 0; i < num_curves; ++i)
{
   cur_points = CreatePolyPoints(m_curves[i]);
   curves[i] = &cur_points[0];    // <-- problem
   curve_sizes = cur_points.size();
}
```

You assign the address of the vector element 0 to your `ith` element of `curves` at each iteration - The problem here is that that will be the address of an object that no longer exists. This is because the contents of the vector will no longer exist once `cur_points` gets reassigned next time in the loop iteration, therefore the pointers you are storing do not point to valid objects - they point to objects that have been destroyed already. When your loop finished, the vector will contain the contents returned in the **last** call to `CreatePolyPoints`. If you want to make sure that all the `cv::Point` objects still exist at the point you call `cv::fillPoly` you should consider passing the vector by reference to the `CreatePolyPoints()` function rather than return a new vector by value each time. This will ensure that ALL items you add via `CreatePolyPoints` will still exist once your loop finishes

Comment: Conceptually, the `points` vector gets copied, then the original vector gets destroyed when the `CreatePolyPoints` function is exited, and the caller receives the copy as the return value.  However, due to C++ return-value optimization, the function may just pass that vector back to the caller instead of copying it, so it is the caller which will eventually destroy it.

Comment: Okay, two related questions.  Am I approaching this correctly?  Secondly, how do I ensure out of scope? Is the `delete [] curves` sufficient?  Do I need to iterate through `curves` and `delete [] curves[i]`?  Who handles that?

Comment: @Constantin Those responses you quote do not imply that your `cur_points` variable will exist once `DoSomething()` exits unless I totally misread them.

Comment: No I agree.  Your edit clarified well.  The points only need to exist within DoSomething().  I have removed my comment.

Comment: @Constantin One thing in your code I noticed is that you create 2 arrays with `new` one an array of `cv::Point*` and the other an array of `int`. You are only deleting one of them - the `int` array is not getting deleted - is that your intention?

Comment: Great, makes perfect sense.  Thank you for helping me work through this mathematician.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly where my secondary confusions stemmed from, and I agree with your understanding.

Answer (score 2):

`cur_points` is a variable with automatic storage duration.  It comes in to existence when it is declared, here:

```
std::vector<cv::Point> cur_points;
```

...and persists as long as it's enclosing scope persists.

Since the "enclosing scope" in this case is the function `void DoSomething()` itself, `cur_points` will go out of scope and be destroyed (automatically) when the function returns.

**Edit** Now, the above is the simple answer.  The complete answer is actually a bit more complex because temporaries are also involved.

The function `CreatePolyPoints` returns this `vector` by-value.  Strictly adhering to the semantics of this function and the return value means that the `points` object created locally within that function will be destroyed when `CreatePolyPoints` returns, and a new temporary `vector` will be constructed from `points`.  That temporary is what's actually returned from the function.  This temporary is then copied to your `cur_points` variable (via copy-assignemnt), and then the temporary is destroyed.

This is a lot of wasteful copying, but there's a bit more to the story.  The C++ Standard also has a rule (referred to as the "AS-IF" rule) which states that a compiler can change your code in any way it sees fit, so long as the behavior of your program is the same **as if** the compiler had made no changes, considering side-effects.

What the above means is that compilers have a major optimization opportunity to eliminate all these temporaries in many cases, including this case, by copying the return *directly* to the `cur_points` variable instead of thru a temporary.  This optimization in it's most general form is called "Return Value Optimization," and most (all?) modern compilers do it frequently.  When this happens (which it will here usually), the behavior is exactly as I laid out before my edit here.

Comment: What about these responses? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703302/c-vector-return-vs-parameter

Comment: @Constantin: Hold on, I'll read your link.  Meantime, read my edit please.

Comment: @Constantin:  I'm not sure how the responses you linked to contradict what I've said?  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I must have misread your question, originally I thought you mentioned that it gets deleted at the end of `CreatePolyPoints`.  I completely understand and agree with your analysis.  -- Last question, notice that cur_points gets set every loop iteration.  FURTHERMORE, notice I cheat with a `&cur_points[0]`.  Will that data be cleared at the end of each loop iteration?  That is the scope for that "temporary" vector

Comment: @Constantin:  When you say "that data,"  what do you mean, exactly?  Unless I'm misunderstanding you, the asnwer is no -- nothing gets "cleared out" within the for loop.  No automatics variables are declared within the scope of the loop, and nothing is erased or `delete`-ed in the loop.

Comment: Each iteration we create a new `std::vector<cv::Point>` in `CreatePolyPoints` and return it to the for loop.  Inside the for loop, we take the first element of that new std::vector and store it in one of the curves `curves[i] = &cur_points[0]`.  Later we use `curves` which needs to be an array of `cv::Point` arrays, in `cv::fillPoly`.

Comment: @Constantin:  Neihter `cur_points` nor `curves` are cleared out at the iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of DoSomething that does not leak, and with bugs removed:

```
void DoSomething()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> curves;
  // so long as I do not resize this, or change its length,
  // curves[x].data() will remain valid
  curves.resize( m_curves.size() );

  for(int i = 0; i < num_curves; ++i)
  {
    curves[i] = CreatePolyPoints(m_curves[i]);
  }
  // create buffers of the correct size for the legacy API:
  std::vector<v::Point*> curve_ptrs(curves.size());
  std::vector<int> curve_sizes(curves.size());
  for(int i = 0; i < curves.size(); ++i)
  {
    curve_ptrs[i] = curves[i].data();
    curve_sizes[i] = curves[i].size();
  }

  // call the legacy API:
  cv::fillPoly(m_roi, curve_ptrs.data(), curve_sizes.data(), num_curves, ... );
}
```

Comment: Yakk, thank you so much for the C++ style fillPoly approach.  You mention legacy API?  Which part is legacy?

Comment: `cv::fillPoly` takes an array of lengths and an array of pointers to buffers.  I would describe that as a legacy-style API.

Comment: AH I understand, is there a cleaner way to approach it?

Comment: Yes.  Take a const reference to a std vector of std vector of points for example.