# Stack variable being returned

Tags: c++

I was reading the following question:

[How to "return an object" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350385/how-to-return-an-object-in-c)

(which asks about returning objects in C++)

and in particular, the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3350418/997112

```
Thing calculateThing() {
    Thing thing;
    // do calculations and modify thing
     return thing;
}
```

surely this answer won't work because the variable defined will no longer exist, as it was on the stack and only in scope for the duration of the function?

Comment: Since `thing` is being returned by value here, there is no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `thing` inside that function will destroy after return, but it will be copied to another `Thing` object at caller side.

```
Thing new_thing = calculateThing();
```

`new_thing` has the content of returned `thing` from `calculateThing`.

*Note: There is a tricky point, I assume there is well defined copy-constructor or assignment-operator, in case of have `new`/`delete`  stuffs in `Thing`.*

**UPDATE:**
As juanchopanza commented, [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) will avoid creating `thing` inside that function. In fact `new_thing` will replaced by `thing` implicitly and an extra copy will not be done. Obviously no destruction will be happen.

Comment: Our of curiosity, could you elaborate in depth on your point about "new/delete stuffs in Thing"?

Comment: It's long to tell in comments. Read this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/78946/C-Copy-Constructor-in-depth).

Comment: @user997112 be aware that return value optimization (see my answer) means that in actual fact, it is most likely that the `thing` in the function **will not** be destroyed when the function returns, but rather, `new_thing` and `thing` will be one and the same object. This is important to consider because often people get worried about the cost of copying when returning by value, but with RVO there is no cost.

Answer (score 1):

It will work, because (at least semantically), you are returning a *copy* of the variable to the caller. Now, the actual copy might be elided via [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), so in this kind of expression

```
Thing t = calculateThing();
```

the `thing` from the function body would usually get constructed into the location of `t`. But `t` is effectively a copy of `thing` in the sense that it has the same value.

Answer (score 0):

This works because `thing` is copied/moved in to the return value (the return value is a different object from `thing` unless copy elision takes place, in which case the lifetime of `thing` is extended to the lifetime of the return value).

```
//Here there may be up to three Thing objects.
//- `thing` in the function body
//- the unnamed temporary that is the value of `calculateThing()`
//  (the return value)
//- t
Thing t(calculateThing());
```

All three objects may be the same object if copy elision occurs.

Comment: ah so if we had declared using Thing& thing, then it wouldn't have worked?