# What's the idiomatic way to generate the numbers from 0 to n-1?

Tags: c++, vector, idioms

What's the acceptable C++ idiom for generating the numbers from 0 to n-1, in an arbitrary type, in an array or a vector?

In other words, how would I write:

```
template <typename T> vector<T> generate_integers_upto(size_t n);
```

or

```
template <typename T> T* generate_integers_upto(size_t n);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to "return an object" in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350385/how-to-return-an-object-in-c)

Comment: You would write: `std::vector<T> x(n); std::iota(x.begin(), x.end(), T());`

Comment: Do you actually need the objects to all exist at once? If not then use Boost.Range: `template< class T > iterator_range< counting_iterator<T> > generate_integers_upto(size_t n) { return counting_range<T>(0, n); }`

Comment: @SteveJessop the Boost::Range Library (And the iterator too) shouuld be added to the Standard Library. I always miss that kind of high level numeric abstractions on the Standard Library.

Comment: @Manu343726: I think some of the details are difficult, like managing the various overloads you end up with for algorithms that have multiple forms already with optional predicates or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It rather depends on what you want to do with those numbers.

If you *really* want a range, not a container, then [`boost::irange`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html) will more than suffice. It doesn't even need any [substantial] memory!

It [lets you do cool stuff like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/108cf40e33ca5b77):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>

using boost::irange;
using std::cout;

int main()
{
    for (auto i : irange(0, 42))
        cout << i << ' ';
}

// 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
// 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41
```

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic way would be to return by value. You could use [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) to fill the vector for simplicity, but this is secondary:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> generate(std::size_t n)
{
  std::vector<T> v(n);
  std::iota(std::begin(v), std::end(v), T());
  return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just return by value and let the compiler decide what (RVO, move return, etc) is more efficient:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> generate( std::size_t n , T begin = 0u )
{
    std::vector<T> result( n );

    std::iota( std::begin( result ) , std::end( result ) , begin );

    return result;
}
```

Note that the default return type is `unsigned int`. Of course you could change the value passed to the function to change the return value, or specify explicitly the return type:

```
int main()
{
    auto sequence = generate<float>( 100 );
}
```

This implementation is based on the [`std::iota()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) standard library algorithm.

Comment: I believe the question is about the idiomatic implementation of this function rather than how to declare it.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy ok, I have updated the answer showing one implementation example using `std::iota()`.

Comment: Dropped the rvalue reference from the signature.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function to create the array for you, then return `std::vector` by value.

Returning a reference, as your first example does, is either invalid (if the vector was a local variable that's now been destroyed) or weird and error-prone (since there's now a vector somewhere that needs managing somehow).

Returning a pointer, presumably to an allocated array, is error-prone since there's nothing to make sure the caller deallocates it correctly.

A more flexible alternative is to take an iterator range. It might make sense to overload it for both a pair of iterators:

```
std::vector<int> v(10);       // non-empty vector
generate(v.begin(), v.end()); // replace existing elements
```

and an iterator and a size:

```
std::vector<int> v;             // empty vector
generate(back_inserter(v), 10); // insert new elements
```

Note that the C++11 library has a `std::iota` which acts like the first version (and can be used to implement any of these), but nothing like the second.