# What is the correct approach while defining a function that generates a vector of elements C++

Tags: c++, vector, parameter-passing, instance, pass-by-reference

I have to define a function in C++ that generates a vector of classes Foo and returns it.

I can define it in different ways, that are all quite equivalent:

C style parameter passing:

```
void generateFooVector(vector<Foo> * result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Foo f = Foo();
        result->push_back(f);
    }
}
int main()
{

    vector<Foo> result;
    generateFooVector(&result);
}
```

Reference passing passing:

```
void generateFooVector(vector<Foo> & result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Foo f = Foo();
        result->push_back(f);
    }
}
int main()
{
    vector<Foo> result;
    generateFooVector(result);
}
```

Instancing the vector and returning the pointer:

```
vector<Foo> * generateFooVector()
{
    vector<Foo> * result = new vector<Foo>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Foo f = Foo();
        result->push_back(f);
    }
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    vector<Foo> * result = generateFooVector();
}
```

C style passing and instancing Foo class:

```
void generateFooVector(vector<Foo *> * result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Foo * f = new Foo();
        result->push_back(f);
    }
}
int main()
{
    vector<Foo *> result;
    generateFooVector(&result);
}
```

Reference passing + Foo instances:

```
void generateFooVector(vector<Foo *> & result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Foo * f = new Foo();
        result->push_back(f);
    }
}
int main()
{

    vector<Foo *> result;
    generateFooVector(result);
}
```

Vector instance + Foo instances:

```
vector<Foo*> * generateFooVector()
{
    vector<Foo*> * result = new vector<Foo*>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Foo * f = new Foo();
        result->push_back(f);
    }
    return result;
}
int main()
{

    vector<Foo *> * result = generateFooVector();
}
```

Passing by value:

```
vector<Foo> generateFooVector()
{
    vector<Foo> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Foo f = Foo();
        result->push_back(f);
    }
    return result;
}
int main()
{

    vector<Foo > result = generateFooVector();
}
```

And maybe there are lots of other solutions.

All the current ways have different implications on how the memory is allocated, in the scope.

Maybe I've a lack of theory, but I'm really confused on how can I decide which is the better alternative for each use case, and why one is better than another. Can you help me?

Comment: Note: use `std::generate`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to "return an object" in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350385/how-to-return-an-object-in-c)

Comment: Hundred push_backs? Did you hear about [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) and [fill](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)?

Comment: @Tacet, Or `reserve` and `std::back_inserter`. `std::fill` isn't useful if you need to call the function every time, but perhaps that's the case here.

Comment: @chris I understand that it's important, but it was just an example. That is not the point. I'm asking about how to return a collection of elements.

Answer (score 8):

Just do

```
vector<Foo> generateFooVector()
{
    return vector<Foo>(100);
}
```

It's called `modern c++`.

Comment: Best answer length to question length ratio ever.

Comment: It's not even modern. Copy elision has been in the standard forever, and compilers have supported it since 1962.

Comment: This is probably fine in C++11 because of move semantics but might prove problematic in C++99 due to the need to copy on return.

Comment: hm, the magic number 100 is not part of the interface, that should be a runtime parameter

Comment: @doron No, unless your compiler/platform does not support RVO.

Comment: @doron (N)RVO would still most likely take care of this.

Comment: In this case Return Value optimization should work but in a more complicated case, you still might get excessive copying.

Comment: @doron: The first rule of optimization (and of my carpenter of a grand-da) => *Measure Twice, Cut Once*. Copy Elision or Move Semantics should take care of excessive copying in the vast majority of cases, if it does not and it was necessary then extra brain-power can be invested.

Answer (score 5):

That function is already defined in the Standard Library and is called the constructor of `std::vector<Foo>`. You can call it as (C++11 style)

```
auto v = std::vector<Foo>(n); // create n default constructed Foo() objects
```

or in C++98 style (also valid in C++11) as

```
std::vector<Foo> v(n);
```

**I would not try to wrap this.**

- first, you don't want to hide magic numbers like 100 inside it instead of inside a parameter list (template or runtime).
- another reason not to wrap a constructor is to avoid confusion on behalf of your readers. If I were to encounter a `generateVector` function, the first question would be: "is this function doing anything else/extra compared to a plain constructor call?"

Comment: OK, but what is the point of the `auto` here? Is there anything to be gained over the "normal" way of instantiating the object?

Comment: it's [Sutter's AAA](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) (almost always auto) style that he recommends for C++11. One advantage is that all variable declarations/definitions have the same left-to-right form.

Comment: Yeah, I know about AAA. But in this case it looks like an anti-pattern.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think anti-pattern is too strong, since there is no efficiency loss or anything, but only a matter of readability. Anyway, I updated to reflect that the old style is still valid in C++11.

Comment: I guess it will take some getting used to, or will get discarded. But it does place extra requirements on the type: it must be copyable or move-copyable.

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't think so, there are no extra requirements on `Foo` here. Copy elision or move semantics on `std::vector<Foo>` is just assigning another pointer to the allocated memory and nulling out the original one, not actually doing something with the `Foo` objects.

Comment: The copy or move-copy constructor must be accessible, even if the copy gets elided. Anyway, it isn't a big issue.

Comment: @juanchopanza ah I see, and that is more than the container requirements for `Foo` to be compatible with `vector<Foo>`? What kind of types can be inserted in `vector` but not moved/copied?

Comment: I was talking about `auto t = T(x)` in general, not in the particular case of `std::vector`. It is an idiom that places more requirements than `T t(x);`.

Answer (score 1):

I really see two principal different implementations - `vector<Foo*>` and `vector<Foo>`. All other are the variations of parameter passing.

As you know, vector copies elements when adding and calls elements destructors when vector is deleted. So in the case of `vector<Foo*>` you are avoiding copying of objects which can gain if objects are very large. **But** you're responsible for deleting the memory. So it would be better to store smart pointers with auto deletion, say `vector<shared_ptr<Foo>>` or `vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>` (here move logic required). The type of the pointer depends on your application logic.

BTW,

```
 Foo* pFoo = new Foo;  // also default constructor call
```

(do you know [the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new) with `new Foo()` ?)

```
 vector<Foo> v(n);  // init vector with n Foo objects calling default ctor
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably take the reference passing approach taken above.

Generally in C and C++ you do not want to return objects that need to be deallocated later because you can cause leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends a lot on the actual usage - most critically how heavy is foo?
If foo is a light-weight object AND a POD-like type then I would use

```
Vector<Foo> generateFoo();
```

otherwise perhaps something like:

```
Vector<Foo*> generateFoo();
```

might be more useful.

The standard type are efficient and mostly like to be copied so their is little advantage to the vector* solutions.
In general it is probably unwise to return (or use) a raw pointer that requires a later delete - so easy to generate leaks within this kind of architecture. So perhaps look at the various smart pointer options for your foo object.

Comment: This pointer/smart pointer approach is over-complicating things for no reason.

Comment: if foo is a large or expensive object (say an open file buffer) then you have to use some kind of pointer (as making copies is not practical).

Comment: No, because, more likely than not, the copy will be elided. So you should only play complicated pointer tricks *if* your compiler/platform cannot perform the copy elision and *if* you don't have a cheap move constructor.