# A function that returns a queue?

Tags: c++, queue

I'm trying to figure out how queues work in C++ and am getting stuck when dealing with objects. I seem to only be able to get a return address instead of the name of the object (which is what I really want). It's also showing an error when I try to pop the element from the queue. My code is as follows:

Buyer.h file

```
#ifndef BUYER_H
#define BUYER_H
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include "Order.h"
#include "Entity.h"
#include "Seller.h"

class Order;

class Seller;

class Buyer : public Entity {

public:
 Buyer(const std::string &, const std::string &, double);
 virtual ~Buyer() { }; // when step is added make this virtual
 void addSeller(Seller *);
 std::queue<Seller*> getSellers() const;
 void addOrder(Order *);
 std::queue<Order*> getOrders() const;
 virtual void list() const override;
 virtual void step() const override;

private:
 std::queue<Order*> orders;
 std::queue<Seller*> sellers;

};
#endif
```

Buyer.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include "Buyer.h"
#include "Seller.h"
#include "Order.h"
#include "Entity.h"
using namespace std;

Buyer::Buyer(const std::string &name, const std::string &id, double balance)
  : Entity(name, id, balance)
{
  // initialize seller and order queue??
} // Constructor

void Buyer::addSeller(Seller *s) {
  sellers.push(s);
} // addSeller

std::queue<Seller*> Buyer::getSellers() const {
  while(!sellers.empty()) {
    return sellers;
  } // while
} // getSellers

void Buyer::addOrder(Order *o) {
  orders.push(o);
} // addOrder

std::queue<Order*> Buyer::getOrders() const {
  while(!orders.empty()) {
    return orders;
  } // while
} // getOrders

void Buyer::list() const {
  Entity::list();
  std::cout << "Orders:\nOrder contains:";
  std::cout << "\nSellers:\n";
  int i = 0;
  while(!sellers.empty()) {
    std::cout << sellers.front() << "\n";
    sellers.pop();
  } // while
} //list

void Buyer::step() const {
  std::cout << "\nstep enter\n"
            << "step exit\n\n";
} // step
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "return an object" in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350385/how-to-return-an-object-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

(This isn't a full answer but it is too big to go in a comment)

It's OK to return `std::queue<Order *>`, and so on. However, you need to be clear on who *owns* the objects being pointed to; i.e. who is responsible for deleting them.

When you return a `std::queue<Order *>`, what happens is that the returned queue is a copy of the original one, however all the pointers point to the same object that the original one pointed to . (This is a sort of "shallow copy").

If you then `delete` anything in the returned queue, you will cause the original queue to malfunction because it will be accessing deleted memory.

As such, this is a fragile design because the caller can easily cause the object to screw up despite the fact that `getOrders` is a const function.

One "solution" is to make the containers contain `shared_ptr<Order>` instead of `Order *`. Then everything happens automatically; the caller can add or delete to his heart's content.

If it is not strictly necessary for the containers to contain pointers, consider using containers of objects: `std::queue<Order>`. The benefit of this approach is that the default copy and move semantics are all correct.

Another approach to consider is having `getOrders()` and `getSellers()` return a const reference, instead of returning a copy of the queue.

NB. In `Buyer::getSellers()`, and `getOrders()` if it is empty then you fall off the end of the function without `return`ing, causing undefined behaviour. You need to either return something (what's wrong with returning an empty queue?) or `throw` an exception.