# Assigning a variable to dynamically allocated return value?

Tags: c++

I am trying to assign a variable to a return value but the deconstructor is called before the values are assigned to pq. I also get the following error which I'm assuming is an attempt to double delete a variable:

_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

```
    PriorityQueue pq;
    pq = FindThroughPaths(a, b);
```

FindThroughPaths(a, b) returns a PriorityQueue.

I may be getting this error because the return value has dynamically allocated member variables.

I am simply trying to find a way to keep the return value of FindThroughPaths(a, b) within the scope and I do not want to create multiple instances just to access it's members. This is an example of what I would like:

```
    PriorityQueue pq;
    pq = FindThroughPaths(a, b);
    while (!pq.IsEmpty) {
         Path tmp = pq.Dequeue();
         std::cout << "\n" << tmp.name << " #" << tmp.number;
    }
```

The constructor, deconstructor, and assignment operator for PriorityQueue:

```
    PriorityQueue::PriorityQueue()
    {
            std::cout << "\nConstructor called." << endl;
            items.elements = new ItemType[maxItems];
            length = 0;
    }


    PriorityQueue::~PriorityQueue()
    {
           std::cout << "\nDeconstructor called." << endl;
           delete[] items.elements;
    }

    PriorityQueue PriorityQueue::operator=(const PriorityQueue &originalPQ)
    {
           //This function is started after the return value, the right operand, has been deconstructed.
           std::cout << "\nAssignment called." << endl;
           for (int i = 0; i < maxItems; i++)
                   items.elements[i] = originalPQ.items.elements[i];
           return *this;
     }
```

Comment: I assume you have defined the copy constructor?

Comment: Using `new` and `delete` is a big red flag. To use them properly you need to know about the [Rule of Five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).  But the better approach is to use the Rule of Zero, and store your data in a container that manages its own memory. For example, `items.elements` could be a `vector`.

Comment: The assignment operator should return by reference. (But if you follow the Rule of Zero then you do not need assignment operator,destructor, or copy constructor).

Answer (score 0):

It is a little hard to tell exactly what the problem is without looking at how you are returning the `PriorityQueue` from your `FindThroughPaths` method, but it is likely that the problem is that you are missing a copy constructor in the `PriorityQueue` class.

```
PriorityQueue::PriorityQueue(const PriorityQueue &other)
{
    std::cout << "\nCopy constructor was called" << endl;
    // there are better ways to implement this, but I think this will correctly
    // defer to the assignment operator you wrote
    *this = other;
}
```

When you return an object from a method, the copy constructor is invoked to build the object that will be returned.  If you have not implemented a copy constructor, then a default implementation is used, and that default will not be sufficient in your case.

The destructor will still be called to destroy the PriorityQueue object that is local to the `FindThroughPaths` method.

You might find [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350385/how-to-return-an-object-in-c) about returning an object from a method to be helpful.

Comment: Yes I did forget a copy constructor but for some reason that code did not work. It caused an infinite loop of the assignment operator and copy constructor calling each other.

I got it to work by taking out the assignment operator and just putting it's contents into the copy constructor, with an additional memory allocation at the start.

Comment: I didn't notice earlier, but the operator= is usually defined to return by reference as in `PriorityQueue& PriorityQueue::operator=`.  If you did that, it might avoid the infinite loop.  And, yes, I forgot to allocate the memory at the top of the copy constructor.