# C++: Return a Class Object from an function

Tags: c++, class, memory, memory-leaks

I have read some article on Stackoverlow like [How to “return an object” in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350385/how-to-return-an-object-in-c) about this problem but my problem still exists.

My program implements a Vector Class (vector in Maths). I want to overload an operator `+`, I have try to modify empty object in function or use static member and the results is in my comments on these code below.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Vector {
    double * arr;
    unsigned short dim;

public:
    Vector(const int& d = 0); // This constructor initialize memory for its member

    Vector& operator = (const Vector& v);

    /* This function must return a Vector object
     *
     * Example: Vector v = v1 + v2; // v1.arr = {1, 1, 3}, v2.arr = {1, 0, 1}
     *
     * Then v.arr = {2, 1, 4} // this is just an example

     * When I run it by using empty class like:
     * Vector operator + (const Vector& v) const {
     *     Vector vec();
     *     // Do something with vec;
     *     return vec;
     * }
     * It returns a garbage value.
     *
     * When I run the code below, the GNU compiler inform:
     * C:\Desktop>g++ -Wall -ansi -c Vector.cpp
     * C:\Desktop>g++ -Wall -ansi -o main.exe main.cpp vector.o
     * vector.o:Vector.cpp:(.text+0x33e): undefined reference to `Vector::_vec'
     */

    Vector operator + (const Vector& v) const {

        if (dim == v.dim) {
            _vec = Vector(dim);

            for (int i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
                _vec.arr[i] = arr[i] + v.arr[i];
            }

            return _vec;
        }

        return Vector(0);
    } 

    ~Vector();

private:
    static Vector _vec;
};
```

**Main function for anyone needs it:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    Vector v(-2), v3;
    Vector v2(2);

    cout << "Input vector: ";
    cin >> v;
    cout << v << endl;
    cout << "Input vector: ";
    cin >> v2;
    cout << v2 << endl;

    v3 = v + v2;
    cout << v3;

    return 0;
}
```

*Thanks for reading.*

Comment: Can you explain how this does not work?  Compiler errors?  Logic errors?

Comment: _"It doesn't work"_ is pretty vague. Could you provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks, I will implement it.

Comment: On '+' operator it is possible that the new Vector to be allocated on stack instead of heap and therefore when the '+' function exits to have references to objects that does not exists anymore. You should use new operator to create new Vector instances and then return references to newly created objects

Comment: Or you could add a copy constructor since the default copy constructor will copy the values as memory copy and therefore both instances will have the same the pointer to arr which is not OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it's meant to be regular Vector of doubles (or more like array, since you don't change size yet). And operator+ is memberwise addition of two vectors.

There's lots of begginer mistakes in the sample, so let's get you up to speed first:

1. Don't use other primitive types other than `int`, `double`, `char` or `size_t` without good reason (as you do with short).
2. Don't mix `signed` and `unsigned` (as you do with `dim` and `d`) and don't mix types (as you do with `i` and `dim`) without good reason.
3. Don't pass primitive type by const reference (as you do with `const int& d`)
4. It's better to use constructor [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) for simple things, instead of initializing in the body of constructor
5. `unsigned` can't be smaller than `0`, so the `if (dim < 0)` is redundant.
6. You can pass `1` or even `0` to `new[]`, so your `if` conditions are largely redundant
7. You have to `delete[]` the memory you borrowed. The destructor would be a great place to do that.
8. BTW you declared but not defined your destructor.
9. The `static Vector _vec;` has absolutely no bussiness being there as far as I can see.
10. Oh. Do not return through static vector. Create new one: `Vector resultV(dim);` and return that.

UPDATE1:

11. The `Vector(-2)` will return something evil because you didn't follow 2. Most likely will return `Vector(USHORT_MAX - 2)`.
12. To get it form `cin` and print it from `cout` you need to overload `istream& operator>>( istream&, Vector )` and `ostream& operator<<( ostream&, Vector )`

Apply those and if your problems persist, edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I have learnt these rules but I don't realize these errors until you tell me. It's great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

For your immediate problem, you declare the static member but you don't allocate its memory anywhere.

You need to have

```
Vector Vecor::_vec;
```

in one of the .cpp files.

Also, relying on static variable to return result from an operation is a bad idea. Better look into move semantics.

Comment: Thanks @Arkadiy. Could you tell me it work if I create a copy constructor?

Answer (score 1):

I analyzed your coud and found following problems:

General errors:

- You missed to declare a copy constructor.
- You missed to declare a function for accessing vector values (`operator[]`).

Constructor `Vector(const int& d = 0)`

- Passing an int by const reference is not wrong but useless.
- The `if (dim == 1)` case is wrong: you can't use the same pointer variable to store a double and double[]

Method `Vector& operator=(const Vector& v)`

- It don't handles the cases `dim = 0` and `dim = 1` (anyway the case `dim = 1` is wrong also in constructor and don't really needs a separate handling).

Method `Vector operator+(const Vector& v) const`

- No need to use a static variable here. Probably the error you get is a consequence of errors in constructor.

Destructor `~Vector();`

- Implementation is missing: it should free dynamic memory allocated by other functions

Here is the correct code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Vector 
{
    double* arr;
    int     dim;

public:

    Vector(int d = 0) 
    {
        if(dim < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Dimension could not less than 0. It will be set to 0." << std::endl;
            // Better to throw an exception here!
        }

        if(dim <= 0) 
        {

            dim = 0;
            arr = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            dim = d;
            arr = new double[dim];
        }
    } 

    const double& operator[](int i) const 
    {
        return arr[i]; 
    }

    double& operator[](int i) 
    {
        return arr[i]; 
    }

    Vector(const Vector& v)
    {
        dim = v.dim;

        if(dim > 0)
        {
            arr = new double[dim];

            for(int i = 0; i < dim; ++i) 
            {
                arr[i] = v.arr[i];
            }
        }
    }

    Vector& operator=(const Vector& v) 
    {
        if(this != &v) 
        {
            delete[] arr;

            dim = v.dim;

            if(dim > 0)
            {
                arr = new double[dim];

                for(int i = 0; i < dim; ++i) 
                {
                    arr[i] = v.arr[i];
                }
            }
        }

        return *this;
    }

    Vector operator+(const Vector& v) const 
    {
        if(dim == v.dim) 
        {
            Vector r(dim);

            for(int i = 0; i < dim; ++i) 
            {
                r.arr[i] = arr[i] + v.arr[i];
            }

            return r;
        }

        return Vector(0); // Better to throw an exception here!
    } 

    ~Vector()
    {
        if(arr != NULL) delete[] arr;
    }
};

void main()
{
    Vector v1(3);
    Vector v2(3);

    v1[0] = 1;
    v1[1] = 2;
    v1[2] = 3;

    v2[0] = 2;
    v2[1] = 4;
    v2[2] = 6;

    Vector v3 = v1 + v2;

    std::cout << std::endl << v3[0];
    std::cout << std::endl << v3[1];
    std::cout << std::endl << v3[2];
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The main function produces the output:

```
3
6
9
```